# Changing Spark UI dashboard host and port on SparkContext config (SparkConf)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to change the host of my Spark UI dashboard to `0.0.0.0` on Python.

Currently I have the following to change the port - however, I haven't been able to find the argument which changes the host

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().set('spark.ui.port', '8787')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a SparkSession which will create you a SparkContext. I invite you to follow this article explaining the difference between both : [SparkSession vs SparkContext](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/sparksession-vs-sparkcontext/)

---

As you said, we can change the **port** with the key : `spark.ui.port`

We can do the same with the **host address** : `spark.driver.bindAddress`

You can find [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) more information about which parameters you can add in your configuration.

---

### Example

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('MyApp').config("spark.driver.bindAddress","localhost").config("spark.ui.port","5372").getOrCreate()

input("Press enter to terminate")
```

With this lines of code you can access the Spark UI at : http://localhost:5372

Because I added as config parameter :

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| spark.driver.bindAddress | localhost |

Here, you import SparkSession from the pyspark.sql package then you create a SparkSession and you wait for the next order with the input I added otherwise the process automatically stop after each run (change this as you wish, I just wrote this input as education purpose only).

Comment if you need more info. Hope I was able to help some.